# Сохранение больших объемов данных в базу данных используя entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Программа парсит через VK API пользователей (в среднем в 20-50 потоков) и создает записи в базе данных. У каждого пользователя в среднем 20 групп, 500 фотографий, 200 друзей. Я храню в разных таблицах записи о друзьях, группах, пользователях и фотографиях. Итого, чтобы сохранить 1го пользователя у меня уходит около 721 запросов на вставку в базу. В минуту это 200-300 пользователей- ~216 000 запросов на вставку в базу. 
Из за этого вызов `context.SaveChanges()` отнимает около 6-10 минут на выполнение.

Пробовал использовать пул контекстов - `bulk insert`, среднее время- 4-6 минут.

`AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;` или `context.AddRange()` дают примерно те же результаты.

Единственное быстрое решение, к которому я пришел - бинарно сериализовывать данные пользователя и хранить их в `byte[]`, чтобы на юзера было 4 запроса вставки. Это сократило время вызова `context.SaveChanges()` до 1.2 секунды. Но вместе с этим появилась закономерная проблема - чтобы изменить хоть что–то у пользователя, надо десериализовывать и сериализовывать все его данные.

Подскажите, какие существуют подходы сохранения больших объемов данных применимые в данном случае не используя сериализацию?

Comment: доступна ли где-нибудь программа, которой Вы пользовались?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Не нужно вызывать context.SaveChanges() на каждый чих.

   Вставить 1000 записей за 1 context.SaveChanges()  [быстрее](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930982/when-should-i-call-savechanges-when-creating-1000s-of-entity-framework-object), чем на каждую запись вызвать context.SaveChanges().
2. Если у тебя присутсвует какая-то сложная логика, то лучше эту логику вынести в хранимую процедуру.
3. Если БД и приложение находится на разных машинах, то возможно стоит проверить скорость сети.
4. Огромное кол-во индексов может тормозить встаку.
5. Отказаться вообще от EF прии вставках и рулить этим делом через BulkCopy.

   Например, заливаешь все массово в какую-нибудь таблицу на сервере, затем JOB каждые 5 минут опрашивает эту таблицу и выполняет добавление информации по рабочим таблицам.
6. Еще бы профайлером не помешало бы посмотреть запросы, который формирует EF.

   Может быть они не оптимальны и стоит пошаманить с LINQ.

Я бы посоветовал замерить заполнение БД через BulkCopy(Самый быстрый способ множественных вставок) и тогда ты получишь величину к которой ты должен стримиться и выше которой не прыгнешь, используя EF.

Comment: Опечатка в "стремиться" (от stream) даже не по Фрейду, а профдеформация в чистейшем виде: рука не подымается исправлять. )))